# Webpages for near duplicate page analysis

Tags: information-retrieval, duplicates

I am trying to built Near Duplicate Analyzer for Web pages. From where I can get similar web pages to be input for performing this experimentation. (Crawling search engine for a particular query didn't seemed a good option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

- Press releases from different websites
- News articles on different websites
- Wikipedia in the current and older versions (edits are the changes)
- Unix man pages on different servers
- Internet RFCs in different formats: text, XML, or HTML

Here are some sample URLs for RFCs:

- http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc2049/
- http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2049.txt
- http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/pdfrfc/rfc2049.txt.pdf
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2049 (HTML)

Comment: Thanks. These seem to be useful, I will try these links for my application.